# How to show full tooltip(not cropped) inside a div with overflow property?

Tags: angularjs, scroll, tooltip

I'm trying to show the full tooltip in a div that have **overflow-y: auto**
the tool tip is hidden under the div.
**how can I make the tooltip shown above the div?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom tooltip make sure your tooltip style has `position:fixed`

```
position:fixed;
left:auto;
top:auto;
```

For better tooltip UI you should use **bootstrap tooltip** its very easy to intergrate.

Please check link for the same :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/